# How to reflect changes from parent to child component

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to now how can I change a Boolean value from parent to child. On parent page i have a button on `AppBar`, and on body i have a child witch contains an `ListView`.

```
class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ParentState createState() => ParentState ();
}

class ParentState extends State<Parent> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin  {
List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = [
   {'page': Child(isSelected: isSelect), 'title': 'Child'},
   {'page': Child2(), 'title': 'Child2'},
 ];
 bool isSelect= false;
 int _selectedPageIndex = 0;
 Widget _page;

 @override
void initState() {
  _page = _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'];
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  }

 void _selectPage(int index) {
  setState(() {
    _selectedPageIndex = index;
    _page = _pages[index]['page'];
  });
 }

  toggleSelect(){
    setState(() {
      isSelect= !isSelect;
    });
  }

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   child: new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      title: FlatButton(
         onPressed: toggleSelect,
         Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                     Icon(Icons.message, color: isSelect ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey),
                     Text("Select", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: isSelect? Colors.blue : Colors.grey),)
                 ],
             ),
      ),
      body: _page,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: _selectPage,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
          currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Child')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Child2')),
          ]),
 }
}

class Child extends StatefulWidget {
 bool isSelect;
 Child({this.isSelect});

  @override
  ChildState createState() => ChildState ();
}

class ChildState extends State<Child> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin  {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Text(widget.isSelect)  // here is a listView but i have done like this just for example
 }
```

So what I what is that when I click on app bar I what that change to reflect on child page.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found some syntax mistakes in your code when I copied it over. But otherwise it works like you want it to. I'll post the full code. The Text toggles from true to false and back again.

```
class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ParentState createState() => ParentState();
}

class ParentState extends State<Parent> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isSelect = false;

  toggleSelect() {
    setState(() {
      isSelect = !isSelect;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: FlatButton(
            onPressed: toggleSelect,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.message,
                    color: isSelect ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey),
                Text(
                  "Select",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: isSelect ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Child(isSelect: isSelect));
  }
}

class Child extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isSelect;
  Child({this.isSelect});

  @override
  ChildState createState() => ChildState();
}

class ChildState extends State<Child> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.isSelect
        .toString()); // here is a listView but i have done like this just for example
  }
}
```

[image: Before click]
[image: After click]

Comment: What you have added new is only ".toString()". The above example was only to explain my case, because is more complex than that. If i setState on my parent , it doesn't reflect on my child. Did it work properly for you?

Comment: @norganorga Yes your code works perfectly fine for me. I added 2 pictures to my answer. The button disappears because its set to blue. But the text changes. Your approach is correct and there don't seem to be any issues with it.

Comment: I have added some more info, look my edit question. because it's strange why i can't get changes on child component